# Is it possible to run the MSBUILD.SONARQUBE.RUNNER on a CSProj file as opposed to a solution?

Tags: msbuild, sonarqube, sonar-runner

I have a TFS xaml Build template that runs the msbuild.sonarqube.runner start (and end) before and (after the) msbuild task in the xaml.

It all works well enough with a .sln file. As the file under build.

However, when I attempt to use this on a build that runs msbuild on a .csproj file the end process reports that it cannot find the postprocess exe.

"Execution failed. The specified executable does not exist: .sonarqube\bin\MSBuild.SonarQube.Internal.PostProcess.exe"

there no error indication given by the Start command.

is there something special I need to do to get this to work, or is this a limitation of the MSBuild runner?

Please help. 
My whole team is keen to use the tool, but as it is only a fraction of the existing builds are being analyzed

thanks

Jeff Gedney

Answer (score 2):

The `begin` and `end` commands of the SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild, as well as all `msbuild` commands **MUST** be launched from the same current working directory. Indeed, they will all need access to the `.sonarqube` folder that is created by the `begin` command.

Other than that, you can launch MSBuild on a *.csproj file instead of a *.sln if you prefer - that is supported by the SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild.

I've created the following ticket to improve the error message in case `end` is launched from the wrong folder: https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARMSBRU-160

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you put yourself in the root folder of the project you want to analyze, then run the following commands:

a.MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe begin /k:"sonarqube_project_key" /n:"sonarqube_project_name" /v:"sonarqube_project_version"

b.Build the project, for example: msbuild /t:Rebuild

c.MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe end

Check:http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/C%23+Plugin

Comment: this doesnt work until you use it with "-D" i.e declaring the property.